# Simple recursion with yield?

Tags: python

If I put it like this, I see all the combinations in all_items. However, if I do not want to store all combinations and put yield instead, it does not work. Any idea?

```
all_items = []
def get_val(n,last):
    if n < 5:
        for k in range(-1,1+1,1):
            get_val(n+1,last+[k])
    else:
get_val(0,[])
        all_items += [last]
```

Comment: You aren't using the `yield` keyword in the code you posted

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working.

Comment: And indent it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
def get_val(n, last):
    if n < 5:
        for k in range(-1, 1+1, 1):
            yield from get_val(n+1, last+[k])
    else:
        yield last

get_val(0, [])
```

Works in Python 3.3+, below that you can replace `yield from get_val(n+1, last+[k])` with:

```
for thing in get_val(n+1, last+[k]):
    yield thing
```

Comment: Where did this new keyword "from" come from? Thank you, I would have never realized this solution.

Comment: `yield from` [was added in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html)